# PDO clear bound parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I create a sub object of "shortcut" methods such as return_all and other methods to run with PDO as a database object.

In short, all of my queries (be it insert, update, delete or select) goes through 2 different methods, the last one I call execute which looks like this:

/*
     * execute_prepared_sql() will prepare SQL based on the users parameters:
     * 
     */

```
private function execute_prepared_sql() {
    if ($this->prepare_sql() == true) {
        try {
            $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($this->sanitized_sql);
            $this->stmt->execute($this->bound_parameters);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            set_debug($e->getMessage(), true);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I then have methods which looks like this:

```
 public function return_active_partners() {
    if ($this->select(array("query_tables" => $this->table_name, "conditions" => array("AND" => array("partners.status" => 1))))) {
        $this->stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

The above method will then effectively return the results ($this->select() calls the execute_prepared_sql() method.

This all works perfectly fine, but I have this extremely annoying issue where at times (and really at random) I get a "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound" error. It appears to happen a lot more when I do 2 queries after eachother (say I delete a row and then return a result set of the remaining rows)

What appears to happen is the bound parameters don't get removed during the execute_prepared_sql() call. I was under the impression that when execute() is called all bound parameters would be "reset" or cleared, but this appears to not be the case.

My question is, how can I clear any bound parameters a PDO statement may have stored to ensure I don't use the same parameters twice? Or is there something else you can see which I'm doing wrong which may be the issue?

Comment: Do not speculate of reasons. Everything got cleaned. If you get `Invalid parameter number: ` error that means that there is invalid parameter number and nothing else. You need better version of set_debug() to catch the problem.

Comment: You're a God "Your Common Sense" :) After literally a week I realise now I'm looking at the wrong place. I have properties like $this->conditions = false; which get completed during the prepare_sql() method. When I do another query, I never cleared them, so they were using the previous one.